# How to report the effect of covariates in post-matching analysis?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, causality, matching

I have conducted genetic matching using the `MatchIt` package in R with the ultimate aim to compare the effect of the transition to a new form of land management. I got the matching weights (using `match.data`) and fit an `lmer` model (where sites are nested within landscapes) that also includes the percentage of habitat patches as a covariate. I have assessed the effect of land management using `avg_predictions` and `avg_comparisons`. However, I also want to report whether or not habitat patches have an effect on my outcome (note: I did also match on habitat patches). Can I also use `avg_predictions` or do I have to use `summary()` or `anova()` or `car::Anova()` to report the effect of habitat patches?

Answer (score 5):

This is invalid, do not do this. You cannot validly interpret the relationship between covariates and the outcome. Doing so is [known](https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kws412) as the table 2 fallacy. It is a fallacy because the interpretation of the effect of the covariates depends on where they fall along the causal path among the covariates and treatment. The effect is a direct effect (i.e., not through the treatment or any covariates that follow from the covariate of interest), it is confounded because you only adjusted for confounders of the treatment, not this covariate, and it is subject to collider bias because the covariates that come after it are confounded. There is no useful way to interpret such an effect, whether you look at coefficients or marginal effects. If you are interested in the causal effect of this variable on the outcome, do a second causal analysis that treats that variable as focal. if you are merely interested in its association with the outcome, you need to be clear about what kind of association and which variables you need to condition on and which you need to avoid conditioning on to yield such an association.

Comment: Thank so much you, that's extremely helpful. As the covariate of interest (% habitat patches) is continuous, I wouldn't be able to conduct another matching analysis. Would you recommend weighing (using WeighIt) in this case?

Comment: P.S. I am also guessing that it would not be appropriate to directly compare the effect sizes between variables after re-doing the matching and post-matching analyses?

Comment: If you are interested in the causal effect of % habitat patches, you need to do a complete causal analysis of that variable like you did with your primary treatment variable, adjusting for all confounders and not adjusting for bias-inducing variables. Weighting is one way to estimate the effects of a continuous treatment, but there are others, including matching, regression, and double robust methods. Weighting can be a good choice and is easy to implement in WeightIt.

Comment: You should not even look at the coefficients of any non-treatment variables in any outcome regression model. They have no useful interpretation and their comparison does not provide any benefit. Focus on one variable per analysis and do what you can to eliminate the bias in its effect estimate. Everything else is a nuisance parameter that should not be engaged with.

Comment: Thank you! I meant comparing the outcomes of the two separate causal analyses, i.e., one where the primary treatment variable is the predictor and one where the % habitat patches is the predictor of interest. Would it make sense to compare the outcomes or is this not valid as they are completely different analyses?

Comment: Slightly off-topic now, but I thought that matching doesn't work or at least does not perform well when the predictor variable is continuous!?